How to reconcile the Prophet's affliction with poison and sorcery with the hadith about the benefits of Ajwa dates?

(43) Chapter: Al-'Ajwa (a special kind of date).

Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "He who eats seven 'Ajwa dates every morning, will not be affected by poison or magic on the day he eats them."


(14)Chapter: If a Dhimmi practises magic, can he be excused?

Narrated Aisha: Once the Prophet (ﷺ) was bewitched so that he began to imagine that he had done a thing which in fact he had not done.


(83)Chapter: The sickness of the Prophet (saws) and his death

Narrated `Aisha: The Prophet (ﷺ) in his ailment in which he died, used to say, "O Aisha! I still feel the pain caused by the food I ate at Khaibar, and at this time, I feel as if my aorta is being cut from that poison."




Aren't these Hadiths contradictory?
If the prophet knew that Al-Ajwa could protect someone from poison or magic, why didn't he eat that date regularly in order to protect himself from poison or magic?

They are obviously not contradictory unless you can establish that the Prophet ﷺ ate 7 Ajwa dates on the days that he was poisoned and bewitched. There are several possible reasons for why he did not eat them, such as:

He did not desire to do so, rather he chose something else which he considered was better for himself. For example it is known that he used to keep continuous day and night fasts (wisal) as an act of worship. In such fasts he would not be able to eat dates everyday.
Or Allah might have destined undergoing these afflictions for him due to some wisdom such as that he could provide an example to the Muslims on how to deal with witchcraft or so that he be given the status of a martyr by being poisoned.

The dates might not have been available, as there were times that he did not have any food.

He might have forgotten on some days.


It is also possible that he did eat the dates on the days that the poisoning and bewitching occurred, this can also be explained such as:

The hadith could mean that the dates provide protection in most cased but not necessarily always, similar to how other medicines and precautionary measures function.

The protection applies till nightfall according to a wording of the hadith, the poisoning or witchcraft could have happened after sunset.



This involves taqdeer (divine decree); the Ajwa Dates method is not guaranteed to be an absolute cure. It only works if God allows the shifa (healing) from the practice(ritual) or dua (supplication) to be accepted. If God decrees that a person will die from poison, the Ajwa dates will not help, as the healing in any dates or medicine is placed in them by God Himself.
There is a good article on this report that can be found here:
https://medium.com/@Daraqutni/the-hadith-of-ajwa-dates-an-analysis-85a876d2659a
